# Why is getDocs Function not Consistently Retrieving Firestore Data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently working on a project that involves fetching data from a Firestore database using Firebase in a React application. The specific problem I'm encountering is with the getDocs function, which retrieves documents from a collection named "categories."

Sometimes, when I load the app, the data fetching works perfectly fine, and I see the expected results in the console. However, at other times, the getDocs function doesn't seem to be executing properly, and I don't receive any data.

I've added logging statements in the code to trace the flow, and I can see that the function is being called, but the logs indicating the successful data retrieval (debug 2, debug 3) are not consistently showing up in the console. Also, when debug 2or debug 3 is not executing it should go to the catch block and print debug 4 in console. But it is not doing that too!

I've checked Firestore security rules, network connectivity, and other potential issues, but I'm still trying to figure out why this inconsistency is happening. If any of you have experience with Firebase or React, could you take a look at the code snippet below and let me know if anything stands out to you?

```
const getPosterList = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('debug 1');
    const data = await getDocs(postersCollectionRef);
    console.log('debug 2', data);
    const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    }));
    setItemProduct(filteredData);
    console.log('debug 3', filteredData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching poster list:', err);
    console.log('debug 4', err);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
    getPosterList();
  }, []);
```

I've been troubleshooting the issue with the getDocs function inconsistency in my React app that fetches data from a Firestore database using Firebase

Comment: If you see **debug 1** in the console and then no **debug 2** or **debug 4** it means that the `getDocs` promise is not fulfilled or rejected. Take a look at your browser's devTools **Network** tab to see if the request to the Firebase server is **pending**

Comment: I have added a setItemProduct(filteredData); once the promise gets fulfilled it should have the values. But it is not having it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Web SDK v10.4.0 - v10.5.1, you may be experiencing [a hanging query bug](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_1040_-_september_14_2023). Check the version of the SDK you have installed, if it matches these affected version upgrade to v10.5.2 or newer.

If you're uncertain about what version of the SDK is being used by your application, the version will be in the debug logs. Enable debug logs with [`setLogLevel('debug')`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setloglevel).